# ¿Por que me da error el siguiente código?

Tags: c#, class

Encontré el siguiente código en un blog y me gustaría implementarlo para poder usarlo ya que estoy familiarizado con él pues vengo de otro lenguaje que  lo utiliza, sin embargo, cuando intento crear mi clase en C# in lo incluyo me da un error y no he encontrado como solucionarlo, el error es:

> Un espacio de nombres no puede contener directamente miembros como
>   campos o métodos

¿Me pueden sugerir qué debo hacer?

```
  private object IIf(bool Expression, object TruePart, object FalsePart)
    {
      object ReturnValue = Expression == true ? TruePart : FalsePart;

      return ReturnValue;
    }

    private string IIf(bool Expression, string TruePart, string FalsePart)
    {
      string ReturnValue = Expression == true ? TruePart : FalsePart;

      return ReturnValue;
    }

    private bool IIf(bool Expression, bool TruePart, bool FalsePart)
    {
      bool ReturnValue = Expression == true ? TruePart : FalsePart;

      return ReturnValue;
    }

    private int IIf(bool Expression, int TruePart, int FalsePart)
    {
      int ReturnValue = Expression == true ? TruePart : FalsePart;

      return ReturnValue;
    }
```

Comment: En C# ya tiene el [operador ternario ?:](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) no hace falta generar este operador IIf. Mira el codigo lo unico que hace es pasar parametros al operador ?: . ¿Porque necesitas dicho operador nuevo IIf?

Comment: @Jose A. Fernandez, gracias por el dato, me sirve ese operador, como he comentado esoy nuevo y esto aún estoy aprendiendo y cuando no logro encontrar la respuesta en la web publico acá la pregunta, gracias por responder y tendre en cuenta tus comentarios.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

El error se produce porque no se pueden definir métodos directamente dentro de un [`namespace`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/namespace?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(namespace_CSharpKeyword)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%3Dv4.6.1)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue).

Estos deben estar dentro de, ya sea una [clase](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/class?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(class_CSharpKeyword)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%3Dv4.6.1)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) ([`class`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/class?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(class_CSharpKeyword)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%3Dv4.6.1)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue)) o una [estructura](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/struct?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(struct_CSharpKeyword)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%3Dv4.6.1)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) ([`struct`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/struct?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(struct_CSharpKeyword)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%3Dv4.6.1)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue)).

Por ende bastaría con encapsular el código dentro de una [clase](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/class?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(class_CSharpKeyword)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%3Dv4.6.1)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) o [estructura](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/struct?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(struct_CSharpKeyword)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%3Dv4.6.1)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue).

```
public class Foo
{
  private object IIf(bool Expression, object TruePart, object FalsePart)
    {
      object ReturnValue = Expression == true ? TruePart : FalsePart;

      return ReturnValue;
    }

    private string IIf(bool Expression, string TruePart, string FalsePart)
    {
      string ReturnValue = Expression == true ? TruePart : FalsePart;

      return ReturnValue;
    }

    private bool IIf(bool Expression, bool TruePart, bool FalsePart)
    {
      bool ReturnValue = Expression == true ? TruePart : FalsePart;

      return ReturnValue;
    }

    private int IIf(bool Expression, int TruePart, int FalsePart)
    {
      int ReturnValue = Expression == true ? TruePart : FalsePart;

      return ReturnValue;
    }
}
```

Más información [Error del compilador CS0116](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0116) (enlace tomado de la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/254004/77052) de [Alfabravo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/6798/alfabravo))

Comment: Gracias por despejar mi duda, ha sido de gran ayuda. Estoy comenznado a programar en C# y vengo de lenguajes muy viejos y bueno comprenderán lo que sucede cuando se entra al mundo de programación orientada a objetos. Muy amable.

Answer (score 1):

La información que se encuentra en la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0116) indica que este error puede encontrarse si se definen métodos o variables por fuera de una clase.

Entonces, tienes en el código unos métodos definidos, pero no hacen parte de ninguna clase. Encapsula los métodos en una clase o en varias según veas que corresponda.

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es el lugar donde estas implementando el código

Deberías tener definido un namespace para implementarlo, imagino que ya lo estas haciendo cuando pegas el código pero fíjate bien porque seguro tenes mas las llaves

Debería quedarte algo así. (en este ejemplo tendrías todas las funciones dentro de un formulario de windows)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Example
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
       //TU CODIGO
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [answer] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus respuestas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.